# Jure sanguinis - no marriage record for great-grandparents

Tags: citizenship, italian-citizens

I have reserached my path for Italian citizenship Jure sanguinis, and have discovered that my great-grandparents (who were born in Italy) were never *legally* married. My grandfather, their child, was listed as "son" on his father's Naturalization certificate (naturalized after my grandfather was born, so OK there) and my great-grandmother was listed as "wife" on it. Same thing on US decennial census documents - wife and son. So my grandfather was recognized by his father as a legitimate son. Will I have a problem with my application? I do have a "marriage license" for them (from 1918, so after my GF was born) but an actual marriage was never recorded, even if a ceremony was performed. I have searched the church records too.

My grandmother was born in Italy, but my father was born before 1948 so I think that path does not work.

I do not want to go down an expensive legal path.  Please provide any advice you may have.